# obtain dynamically executable path depending on script variable avoiding many ifs

Tags: bash

I want to run determined executable depending on a variable of my script `cur_num`

I have this code, where the paths are "random", meaning they have nothing to do with the secuential `cur_num`:

```
run() {
    if [ $cur_num = "0" ]
        then ~/pathDirName0/execFile0 
    elif [ $cur_num = "1" ] 
        then ~/pathDirName1/execFile1
    elif [ $cur_num = "2" ] 
        then ~/pathDirName2/execFile2 
    elif [ $cur_num = "3" ] 
        then ~/pathDirName3/execFile3
    elif [ $cur_num = "4" ] 
        then ~/pathDirName4/execFile4
    fi
}
```

In case there are lots more of cases, that resulys in a very long `if - elif` statement.
As there are no enums in bash to build the `cur_num`- path relation, is there a cleaner way to obtain the desired path dynamically instead of with lots of `if`s?

Comment: `~/pathDirName"$cur_num"/execFile"$cur_num"` ? `no enums in bash to build the cur_num- path relation` Why would you use enums for that? You can use bash associative arrays or bash arrays.

Comment: paths are "random", meaning they have nothing to do with the secuential `cur_num`, so  I would need to associate the `cur_num` to the path, that would be a hardcoded string

Comment: Then it's just an array.

Comment: As in: `paths=(/path/to/execA /path/to/execB); exec=${paths[cur_num]}` for a minimal example with 2 paths.

Comment: Unless `$cur_num` can take on non-integer values; then you need an associative array (Bash 4.0+).

Answer (score 2):

Try case

```
case $cur_num in
      0) ~/pathDirName0/execFile0;;
      1) ~/pathDirName1/execFile1;;
      2) ~/pathDirName2/execFile2;;
      ...
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

`set` allows you to create arrays in a portable manner, so you can use that to create an ordered array:

`set -- ~/pathDirName0/execFile0 ~/pathDirName1/execFile1 ~/pathDirName2/execFile2 ~/pathDirName3/execFile3 ~/pathDirName4/execFile4`

Then to access these items via an index you do `$x` where `x` is the index of the item.

Now your code would look something like this:

```
run() {
    original="$@"

    : $((cur_num+=1)) # Positional param indexing starts from 1

    set -- ~/pathDirName0/execFile0 ~/pathDirName1/execFile1 \
           ~/pathDirName2/execFile2 ~/pathDirName3/execFile3 \
           ~/pathDirName4/execFile4

    eval "$"$cur_num"" # cur_num = 1, accesses $1 == execFile0

    set -- $original # Restore original args
}
```

A method that is both less and more hacky that would work for indexes above 9 and not mess with the original positional parameters nor use `eval`

```
run() {
    count=0

    for item in "$@"; do
        [ "$count" = "$cur_num" ] && {
            "$item"
            return        
        }

        : "$((count+=1))"
    done

    echo "No item found at index '$cur_num'"
}

cur_num="$1" # Assuming first arg of script.

run ~/pathDirName0/execFile0 ~/pathDirName1/execFile1 \
    ~/pathDirName2/execFile2 ~/pathDirName3/execFile3 \
    ~/pathDirName4/execFile4
```

Comment: That flattens the original positional parameters to a string which is then subject to word splitting.

Comment: I guess then the code could be modified to remove `set` and call `run` with many parameters so that it doesn't mess with the original ones ? It would get it's own array from the params

Comment: Please check the edit.